# LDAP authentication not working

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I made a copy of our dev server and gave it a new name and IP,but now I can not login into it. I think the fault is that I can not get LDAP to verify my pwd. Please could somebody point me in the right direction in what am I still missing.

Ihave made the IP changes in the following places

> etc/hostname
>
> /etc/hosts
>
> /srv/drupal/sites/default/settings.php
>
> /etc/resolv.conf (madesure that the nameservers are ok)
>
> Updatet all the
> firewall servers rules to similar as the dev servers are.

Now I can navigate to the login-page of the site with the new IP,but when I try to use my creditentials it does not give me access like the dev server does.

Have I forgotten to change something on Drupal orr could it be cache related or what?

Thanks for your help

P.S I'm running Drupal on Ubuntu

Comment: I can access the server on putty, win-scp, etc

Comment: Something should be logged.

Comment: Apache has few things in the log like security certificate not matching andnot being able to load dynamic library, but the timestamps do not match the login times

Comment: Drupal has Undefined variable and  access denied info. Soas it worked previously it should not be an issue with the variable

Comment: Access denied does not have any more info, so it is useless